# AssertionError Address changing in hardhat tests

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chai, web3js, hardhat

I'm running into this AssertionError. I'm using a public key generated from the hardhat network. It's saved as a const `const recipient = "0x8626f6940e2eb28930efb4cef49b2d1f2c9c1199";`

As you can see in the error below the value of recipient is changing (capital letters vs lowercase letter). Any idea why and how this can happen?

should work with ERC2981 royalties:

```
  AssertionError: expected '0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9…' to equal '0x8626f6940e2eb28930efb4cef49b2d1f2c9…'
  + expected - actual

  -0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199
  +0x8626f6940e2eb28930efb4cef49b2d1f2c9c1199
```

This is the actual test:

```
it("should work with ERC2981 royalties", async function () {
    const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
    const token = await Token.deploy();
    await token.deployed();

    await token.setRoyalties(0, recipient, 1000);
    let getRoyalties = await token.getRaribleV2Royalties(0);
    assert.equal(getRoyalties[0].value, "1000");
    assert.equal(getRoyalties[0].account, recipient);
    let royalties = await token.royaltyInfo(0, 100000);

    assert.equal(royalties.royaltyAmount.toString(), "10000");
    assert.equal(royalties.receiver, recipient);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the address checksum. You can checksum an address using the `ethers.utils.getAddress()` function ([docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/address/#utils-getAddress)).

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why this is a happens?

Comment: @codestomping In the context of the question: The node returns the address checksumed (through `royalties.receiver`) but your snippet declares it unchecksumed (in `const recipient`)... But if you mean why there's a checksum mechaninsm in the first place: It allows to check if the address is a valid and doesn't contain typos. See the [EIP](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-55) or [this article](https://coincodex.com/article/2078/ethereum-address-checksum-explained/) for more info.